# Exporting SQLite Tables in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

**Situation:** 
I am trying to export my SQLite Tables to a XML file and have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2593752/1184579) as well as a post [deleted from here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/and-bookworm/com/totsp/bookworm/data/DataXmlExporter.java.htm) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567677/an-error-occured-while-executing-doinbackground) (apparently both last links from the same author :) ) 
**Update-2:** I already have another class named `DBAdapter` which extends the `SQLiteOpenHelper`. So I have this:

```
public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
  this.context = ctx;
  DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
  /*...*/
  onCreate()
  /*...*/
  onUpgrade()
  /*...*/
}
```

already in my DBAdapter class file. How can I reuse this?

Also, I tried passing as:

```
DataXmlExporter dm = new DataXmlExporter(SQLiteDatabase 
                           Database(getReadableDatabase ()));
```

But still got an error.

**Update-1:** I used the 2nd Link to implement my solution.

**Problem:** I am getting a Null Pointer Exception; I guess because I haven't initialized my object correctly. 
At the time of calling the DataXmlExporter / exportData method what is supplied as parameter? : 
`DataXmlExporter dm = new DataXmlExporter(WHAT_IS_PASSED_HERE?);`

Thanks..

Comment: @PradeepSimha Hi, Thanks for replying. Its mentioned in the Ques. description with the **code's link**: At the time of calling the DataXmlExporter / exportData method what is supplied as parameter? : 
`DataXmlExporter dm = new DataXmlExporter(WHAT_IS_PASSED_HERE?);`

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need an `SQLiteDatabase`.

for example you can get one with [`getReadableDatabase()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29) or with [`getWritableDatabase()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29).

If you implemented `DatabaseAssistant` like in the first link you provided you have as constructor parameter a reference to a `SQLiteDatabase`....

Comment: nvm I got it. Still +1 for the note. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass SQLiteDatabase Database ( getReadableDatabase () ):

As per constructor

```
public DataXmlExporter(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
  this.db = db;
}
```

And as per comments:
    Android DataExporter that allows the passed in SQLiteDatabase 
    to be exported to external storage (SD card) in an XML format

Comment: I already have another class named `DBAdapter` which extends the SQLiteOpenHelper. So I have this:    `public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
  this.context = ctx;
  DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
 }

 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }....}` already in my DBAdapter class file. How can I reuse this?..by using an object?

Comment: Also, I tried passing as: `..SQLiteDatabase Database(getReadableDatabase ());` I still get an error.

Comment: nvm I got it. Still +1 for the note. :)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to extend the `SQLiteOpenHelper` inside the `DatabaseAssistant` class and used it.